# How to transform angles to a transformation matrix?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I'm working on an open source project. I need to transform three angles (X, Y, Z) to a matrix.

The matrix is a [standard 4x3 homogeneous transformation matrix, where the right column describes the translation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part1.html#attribute-dr3d_transform).

Angles are in input :

- X : 20
- Y : 20
- Z : 0 (disabled)

Rotations are applied in this order : X, Y, Z.

The matrix in output is :

\begin{matrix}
0.993998507596972 & -0.041215528655313 & 0.101332359553377 & 0 \\
0.0593914715688805 & 0.981226162107692 & -0.183488070185209 & 0 \\
-0.09186740444725 & 0.188405145877369 & 0.977785191648479 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}

How can I transform angles to this matrix ? And reverse this matrix to initial angles ?

Thanks for your help, and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. However, I think it is related to [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

Comment: How can i precise my question ?

Comment: Are the 3 angles applied around the coordinates axis? In which order? When you have applied the first rotation do you apply the second one around the axis that has been moved by the first rotation?

Comment: I think angles are applied around the coordinates axis. Rotations are applied in this order : X, Y, Z. I must do reverse enginnering for finding angles :S Thanks for help